# Convert a String to an array of characters or an alternative - Tsql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Getting this done in C# would have been such an easy task, but I am required to do this in sql. Basically, I need to write a tsql function that would convert a given varchar to it's corresponding encoding. For instance, if an input is '123456789' our business rule requires it be converted to 'ABCDEFGHI.' In short, I am trying to convert below c# code to tsql:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = "1234567890";

        char[] oldA = a.ToCharArray();
        char[] newA = new char[10];

        for (int i =0; i<oldA.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (oldA[i])
            {
                case '1':
                    newA[i] = 'A';
                    break;

                case '2':
                    newA[i] = 'B';
                    break;

                    //and so on..
            }
        }

   Console.WriteLine(newA);

   Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

I am confirmed that there is no array like thing in tsql, and most of the answers I came across assumed that it had some kind of delimiter to it, so wasn't particularly very useful.

Thanks.

Comment: how do you encode Z? is it 26? How do you know that is not BF instead? It's pretty easy to do in SQL

Comment: There is an array like thing - it's called a table!

Comment: @ElectricLlama: The input would be always numeric and would be encoded to corresponding alphabet defined by some rule, so encoding Z would not be necessary for my scenario. What is BF? So how do I split a given string into chars and put each character in a row? Any link with an example you could point to?

Comment: What does `0` translate to? `J`? Do you always translate only digits to shown letters?

Comment: @peterm Yes, we could assume that  '0' would be encoded to 'J.' Yes, they would be digits but provided as a varchar parameter not int.

Comment: BF = B (2) + F (6)... or is 26 = Z? THat's my question... what is 12345678910 is it ABCDEFGHIJ or is it ABCDEFGHIA0? We need to know whether this is a fixed width string (one token takes one character) or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc(@expr AS VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
RETURN REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(@expr, '1', 'A'),
                '2', 'B')
              '3', 'C'),
            '4', 'D'),
          '5','E'),
        '6', 'F'),
      '7', 'G'),
    '8', 'H'),
  '9', 'I'),
'0','J')
END
```

or (which is much closer to what you've got in C#)

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc2(@expr AS VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @i AS INT = 1, @chr CHAR(1), @result VARCHAR(255) = ''
  WHILE @i <= LEN(@expr)
  BEGIN
    SET @chr = SUBSTRING(@expr, @i, 1)
    SET @result = @result + 
      CASE @chr
        WHEN '1' THEN 'A'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'B'
        WHEN '3' THEN 'C'
        WHEN '4' THEN 'D'
        WHEN '5' THEN 'E'
        WHEN '6' THEN 'F'
        WHEN '7' THEN 'G'
        WHEN '8' THEN 'H'
        WHEN '9' THEN 'I'
        WHEN '0' THEN 'J'
        ELSE @chr
      END
      SET @i = @i + 1
  END -- WHILE
  RETURN @result
END
```

Sample usage for both functions:

```
SELECT dbo.myfunc(value) result, dbo.myfunc2(value) result2
  FROM
(
  VALUEs ('1234567890'), ('5512314567')
) t(value);
```

Sample output:

```
|     RESULT |    RESULT2 |
|------------|------------|
| ABCDEFGHIJ | ABCDEFGHIJ |
| EEABCADEFG | EEABCADEFG |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fe98/1)** demo

Comment: Thank-you! This, the second one, looks very much like what I am looking for. Cheers!

Comment: IMHO if you were to implement this 'properly in a database you would convert all those CASE statements to records in a table. It depends whether you are after a code-centric solution or a database centric solution.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Define *properly*. IMHO it's not about centricity but rather about requirements and simplicity and keeping it as DRY as possible. But thank you for your input.

Comment: I did not intend to debate your fine answer. It just seemed to me from the wording of the question that the OP could be educated about alternative methods of doing this, which is what I meant about database centric.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that I put in most databases that I work with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_ForLoop](@Start INT , @End INT, @Increment INT = 1)
RETURNS @Loop TABLE 
(
RowNumber INT
)
AS
--=============================================================
-- f_ForLoop
-- 
-- DATE         AUTHOR          DESCRIPTION
-- 17 Apr 2012  Nick McDermaid  Created
--
-- PURPOSE:
-- Return a table that can be joined to with the number of records indicated in parameters
--
-- USAGE:
-- SELECT RowNumber FROM dbo.f_ForLoop(1,10,1)
-- SELECT RowNumber FROM dbo.f_ForLoop(10,1,-1)
-- SELECT RowNumber FROM dbo.f_ForLoop(2,20,2)
--=============================================================
BEGIN
IF @Increment = 0 RETURN
IF @Increment < 0 AND @Start < @End RETURN
IF @Increment > 0 AND @Start > @End RETURN
IF @Increment IS NULL SET @Increment = 1

WHILE NOT (@Start = @End)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Loop (RowNumber) VALUES (@Start)
    SET @Start = @Start + @Increment
END

INSERT INTO @Loop (RowNumber) VALUES (@Start)
RETURN
END
```

Then you can use it something like this:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(50)

SET @YourString='ABCDEFGHIJ'

SELECT 
RowNumber, 
SUBSTRING(@YourString,RowNumber,1) As Token, 
ASCII(SUBSTRING(@YourString,RowNumber,1)) - 64 Result
FROM dbo.f_ForLoop(1,LEN(@YourString),1)
```

This is not exactly what you're after but serves to highlight some functionality.

The next step is to join to a mapping table instead of using ASCII because clearly this is not what you're after. This of course assume that one character is one token.

Answer (score 0):

Based on peterm's second option (if it is safe to assume that all chars in the input will be between '0' and 9'):

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc2(@expr AS VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @i AS INT = 1, @chr CHAR(1), @result VARCHAR(255) = ''
  WHILE @i <= LEN(@expr)
  BEGIN
    SET @chr = SUBSTRING(@expr, @i, 1)
    SET @result = @result + 
      CASE @chr
        WHEN '0' THEN 'J'
        ELSE CHAR(64 + cast(@chr as int))
      END
      SET @i = @i + 1
  END -- WHILE
  RETURN @result
END
```

Or, possibly more efficient, since reduces the number of CAST calls:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc2(@expr AS VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @i AS INT = 1, @b1 BINARY(1), @result VARCHAR(255) = ''
  declare @b VARBINARY(255)
  SET @b = CAST(@expr as VARBINARY(255))

  WHILE @i <= LEN(@b)
  BEGIN
    SET @b1 = SUBSTRING(@b, @i, 1)
    SET @result = @result + 
      CASE @b1
        WHEN 48 THEN 'J'   -- 48 is ascii '0'
        ELSE CHAR(16 + @b1)  -- to get from '1' to 'A' on ASCII chart, need to add 16. 
      END
    SET @i = @i + 1
  END -- WHILE
  RETURN @result
END
```